# How to show day/month number of events in datetime indicator?

Tags: calendar, indicator, events

I configured the datetime indicator to show upcoming Evolution events.
I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 but it is the same with 11.10.

There is a way to show number of day and month in events list, and not only the day name? Without this the list is very confusing because I see "saturday" but don't understand if it's the next, or more later.

Look at this screenshot:

[image: events in indicator]

For the "JoomlaDay" event, I wish to see "sab 22/10 9.00" or could be OK also "sab 22 ott 9.00".

Answer (score 0):

Are you using gnome shell or unity ?

in unity it's an option to enable from the applet settings.
in gnome 3 shell I was not able to do it.

Otherwise in system setting, "date and time"... or change the applet.

Comment: Exactly what option do you mean? Can you post a screenshot?